# How can I mount /home in a usb drive and keep the files?

Tags: linux, shell-script, mount, usb-drive, home

I need to write a script that can mount `/home` in an **USB** drive at the boot and keep all the files in the USB drive after ejecting it.

At every boot, if there is an USB drive plugged in, the script has to check if there is a directory called `/home` in the USB drive and mount it.

In another words, I need to use my USB drive as `/home` and keep all the files there.

How can I mount `/home` in an USB drive and keep all the files there, even after `umount /home`  ?

Comment: what did you tried so far? which distro are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.10. I can mount /home in the usb drive, but the files do not stay there after umount it. I also tried to mount and use rsync to copy the files mounted to the usb drive but that is a kind of slow.

Comment: If you are unmounting the usb drive, then as far as the OS is concerned, the files do not exist. You can mount the drive somewhere else and copy the files to /home. Changes to /home will not show up on the usb drive.

Comment: Why not just leave the usb drive mounted?

Comment: @RobertJacobs, I can not leave it mounted because I need to use this usb drive in other computers and I want to have access to the files of my /home directory. That is why I need to keep all the files in the usb drive, even after umount it.

Comment: If the computers are networked, then I would suggest sharing the directory and mounting them remotely. Otherwise you are stuck making copies and having issues with synchronization.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to keep saving files on the USB drive even after unplugging it?

Comment: @Gilles, after umount the USB drive, the /home directory, which was also mounted, disappears. I just want to keep the files on the USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of things, I found the solution:

If I want to mount `/home/user` on a USB drive and keep all the files there after ejecting it, I have to first mount the USB drive like:

```
mount -o uid=user /dev/sdb1 /hometemp
```

Then, I have to mount the directory `/hometemp` on `home/user` like this:

```
mount --bind /hometemp /home/user
```

It works for me